# Java Student and Class Roster Update Grade

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, methods

I am working on the last part of a project and am stuck when trying to update the grade for a student. See updateGrade sections below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Roster {
    private ArrayList<Student> students;
    private int[] gradingBreakdown;

/**
 * Constructor to create a Roster object.
 * 
 */
public Roster() {
    this.students = new ArrayList<Student>();
}

/**
 * Adds the specified Student to the Roster
 * @param           newStudent  The Student to be added
 * @precondition    newStudent != null
 */
public void addStudent(Student newStudent) {
    if (newStudent == null) {
        return;
    } else {
        this.students.add(newStudent);
    }
}

/**
 * Accepts Student object to be removed
 * @param           oldStudent  The Student to be removed
 * @precondition    oldStudent != null
 */
public void removeStudent(Student oldStudent) {
    if (oldStudent == null) {
        return;
    } else {
        this.students.remove(oldStudent);
    }
}

/**
 * Finds and returns the first student that matches the specified last name.
 * 
 * @param lastName  Student to search for
 * @precondition    lastName != null
 * @return          Found Student object or null if not found.
 */
public Student findStudent(String lastName) {
    if (lastName == null) {
        return null;
    }

    for (Student currStudent : this.students) {
        if (currStudent.getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(lastName)) {
            return currStudent;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

**/**
 * Sets the grade of the specified student to the new grade.
 * 
 * @param lastName  Student to find.
 * @param grade     Grade to update to.
 * @precondition    lastName != null
 *                  0 <= grade <= 100
 */
public void updateGrade(String lastName, int grade) {
    if (lastName == null) {
        return;
    } else {
        this.findStudent(lastName);
    }
}**

/**
 * Builds and return an output string of the class roster
 * 
 * @return A string representation of the class roster.
 */
public String toString() {
    if (this.students.isEmpty()) {
        return "There are no students enrolled";
    }
    String result = "Class roster\n";

    for (Student currStudent : this.students) {
        result += currStudent.getFirstName() + " "
                + currStudent.getLastName() + ": " + currStudent.getGrade()
                + "\n";
    }

    result += "\nMin grade: " + this.getMinimumGrade() + "\n";
    result += "Max grade: " + this.getMaximumGrade() + "\n";
    result += String.format("Ave grade: %.2f\n", this.getAverageGrade());

    return result;
}

/**
 * Builds and returns a summary of the grading breakdown which returns
 * number of A's, B's, C's, etc.
 * 
 * @return The grading breakdown.
 */
public String getGradingBreakdown() {
    this.determineGradingBreakdown();

    String gradeOutput;
    gradeOutput = "A: " + this.gradingBreakdown[0] + "\n";
    gradeOutput += "B: " + this.gradingBreakdown[1] + "\n";
    gradeOutput += "C: " + this.gradingBreakdown[2] + "\n";
    gradeOutput += "D: " + this.gradingBreakdown[3] + "\n";
    gradeOutput += "F: " + this.gradingBreakdown[4] + "\n";

    return gradeOutput;
}

/**
 * Builds and returns a grading histrogram which returns number of A's, B's,
 * C's, etc.
 * 
 * @return The grading histrogram
 */
public String getGradingHistogram() {
    this.determineGradingBreakdown();

    String histogram;
    histogram = "A: " + this.starLine(this.gradingBreakdown[0]) + "\n";
    histogram += "B: " + this.starLine(this.gradingBreakdown[1]) + "\n";
    histogram += "C: " + this.starLine(this.gradingBreakdown[2]) + "\n";
    histogram += "D: " + this.starLine(this.gradingBreakdown[3]) + "\n";
    histogram += "F: " + this.starLine(this.gradingBreakdown[4]) + "\n";

    return histogram;
}

private int getMinimumGrade() {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for (Student currStudent : this.students) {
        if (currStudent.getGrade() < min) {
            min = currStudent.getGrade();
        }
    }

    return min;
}

private int getMaximumGrade() {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (Student currStudent : this.students) {
        if (currStudent.getGrade() > max) {
            max = currStudent.getGrade();
        }
    }

    return max;
}

private double getAverageGrade() {
    int sum = 0;

    for (Student currStudent : this.students) {
        sum += currStudent.getGrade();
    }

    return sum / (double) this.students.size();
}

private void determineGradingBreakdown() {
    this.gradingBreakdown = new int[5];
    for (Student currStudent : this.students) {
        int grade = currStudent.getGrade();

        if (grade >= 90) {
            this.gradingBreakdown[0]++;
        } else if (grade >= 80) {
            this.gradingBreakdown[1]++;
        } else if (grade >= 70) {
            this.gradingBreakdown[2]++;
        } else if (grade >= 60) {
            this.gradingBreakdown[3]++;
        } else {
            this.gradingBreakdown[4]++;
        }
    }
}

private String starLine(int numberStars) {
    String result = "";

    for (int counter = 0; counter < numberStars; counter++) {
        result += "*";
    }

    return result;
   }
}
```

And here is my second class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * Menu-based textual user interface for Roster
 *
 */
public class RosterTUI {
  private Scanner scan;
  private Roster userRoster;

/**
 * Instantiates scanner and assigns Roster object to
 * instance variable
 * 
 * @param object    new Roster object
 */

public RosterTUI(Roster object) {
    this.userRoster = new Roster();
    this.scan = new Scanner(System.in);
}

/**
 * Run, print welcome message
 */

public void run() {
    int choice = 0;
    System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
    String userName = this.scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("\nWelcome " + userName + "!\n");
    while (choice != 6) {
        this.displayMenu();
        System.out.println("Please select an option:");
        String input = this.scan.nextLine();
        choice = Integer.parseInt(input);
        if (choice == 1) {
            this.addStudent();
        } else if (choice == 2) {
            this.removeStudent();
        } else if (choice == 3) {
            this.updateGrade();
        }else if (choice == 4) {
            this.displayStatistics();
        } else if (choice == 5) {
            this.displayBreakdown();
        } else {
            if (choice != 6) {
                System.out.println("Not a valid option.\n");
            }
        }
    } 
    System.out.println("\nThank you for using the application.");
}

/**
 * Menu options for user
 */

public void displayMenu() {
    System.out.println("Main Menu\n");
    System.out.println("1 - Add a student");
    System.out.println("2 - Remove a student");
    System.out.println("3 - Update a student");
    System.out.println("4 - Display class statistics");
    System.out.println("5 - Display grading breakdown");
    System.out.println("6 - Quit\n");
}

/**
 * Adds student based off user input
 */

public void addStudent() {
    System.out.println("Please enter the first name of the student: ");
    String firstName = this.scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter the last name of the student: ");
    String lastName = this.scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter the grade of the student between 0 and 100: ");
    String grade = this.scan.nextLine();
    int userGrade = Integer.parseInt(grade);
    if (userGrade > 100 || userGrade < 0) {
        System.out.println("Grade must be between 0 and 100. Please enter grade: ");
        grade = this.scan.nextLine();
        userGrade = Integer.parseInt(grade);
    }
    Student userStudent = new Student(firstName, lastName, userGrade);
    this.userRoster.addStudent(userStudent);
}

/**
 * This method displays the statistics
 */
public void displayStatistics() {
    System.out.println("\n" + this.userRoster.toString());
}

/**
 * Display grading breakdown and histogram
 */
public void displayBreakdown() {
    System.out.println("\n" + this.userRoster.getGradingBreakdown());
    System.out.println(this.userRoster.getGradingHistogram());
}

/**
 * Removes Student based off last name entered by user
 */
public void removeStudent() {
    System.out.println("Please enter the last name of the student to be removed: ");
    String lastName = this.scan.nextLine();

    if (this.userRoster.findStudent(lastName) == null) {
        System.out.println("A student with the last name of " + lastName + " does not exist.\n");
    } else {
        this.userRoster.removeStudent(this.userRoster.findStudent(lastName));
        System.out.println(lastName + " has been deleted.\n");
    }
}

/**
 * Updated the grade of a student after finding by last name
 */
public void updateGrade() {
    System.out.println("Please first enter the last name of the student: ");
    String lastName = this.scan.nextLine();

    if (this.userRoster.findStudent(lastName) == null) {
        System.out.println("A student with the last name of " + lastName + " does not exist.\n");
    } else if (this.userRoster.findStudent(lastName) != null) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the new grade of the student between 0 and 100: ");
        String grade = this.scan.nextLine();
        int userGrade = Integer.parseInt(grade);
        if (userGrade > 100 || userGrade < 0) {
            System.out.println("Grade must be between 0 and 100. Please enter new grade: ");
            grade = this.scan.nextLine();
            userGrade = Integer.parseInt(grade);
        }
        this.userRoster.updateGrade(lastName, userGrade);
    }
  }
}
```

I included the code that I have up to this point for each of the updateGrade sections (sorry, lots of code to scroll through to find the main point). I'm not sure on which end my problem is, but the rest of the program works exactly as it should up to this point. Any help with the updateGrade methods would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: add your Student class also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Roster#updateGrade(String, int)` you look for your `Student`:

```
this.findStudent(lastName);
```

but don't use the result of this method call. You probably want:

```
Student foundStudent = this.findStudent(lastName);
if (foundStudent != null) {
    // found
    foundStudent.setGrade(grade);
} else {
    // not found..
}
```

or something similar.

*As a side note, you should move the preconditions checks directly in `Roster` class*

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks for the quick response and accurate answer.